# DBD::Oracle Column returns number in unusual format

Tags: oracle, perl, numbers, dbi

I am querying an Oracle database using DBD::Oracle, however, oddly enough the decimals are return as follows:

```
0.1 will be returned as .1
0.97 will be returned as .97
```

Any ideas why this is happening.

I am using the latest version of DBI and DBD::Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the default number format in your session. DBD::Oracle retrieves columns as strings so there will be an implicit TO_CHAR done by Oracle. If you want a different format do a TO_CHAR(column_name, 'FORMAT'). e.g.,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Devel::Peek;

my $h = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=xxx;sid=xxx','xxx','xxx',
                     {RaiseError => 1});
eval {
    $h->do(q/drop table mje/);
};

$h->do(q/create table mje (a number)/);
my @n = (0.1, 0.97);

my $s = $h->prepare(q/insert into mje values(?)/);


foreach (@n) {
    $s->execute($_);
}

$s = $h->prepare(q/select * from mje/);
$s->execute;
while (my @row = $s->fetchrow) {
    Dump($row[0]);
}


$s = $h->prepare(q/select TO_CHAR(a, '09D99') from mje/);
$s->execute;
while (my @row = $s->fetchrow) {
    Dump($row[0]);
}
```

outputs

```
SV = PV(0x9b72810) at 0x9c57ed8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x9d11ec0 ".1"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x9b72810) at 0x9c57ed8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x9d18230 ".97"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x9b72840) at 0x9c57ff8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x9d0d600 " 00.10"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x9b72840) at 0x9c57ff8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x9d0d600 " 00.97"\0
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 12
```

I added the Devel::Peek just to show you they are strings (see the PV) by default so adding the TO_CHAR makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I will give this a try.